# How to check if Intent started in X ms?

Tags: android

I would like to check if camera intent started in 1000 milliseconds, if not, stop starting and do something else.

Answer (score 1):

Intent **can never get started**, it **can be broadcasted and received**.

If you are the broadcaster then you can monitor time of broadcasting, if you are receiver then you can monitor time of received.

To monitor time interval, you should be broadcaster and receiver.

As of now you are trying to monitor time interval for camera intent where you are just a broadcaster. So AFAIK it's not possible to know time interval.